# Targeting first instance of generated classes

Tags: jquery

I have tried to get a solution with css only but im starting to think it cannot be done: a list of events its displayed by date, and im trying to create css classes based on the event date. The format of the date class is <div class="event_date_[here comes the date in a string like this dd-mm-yyyy]", and they are displayed in ascending order so i ended up with this:

```
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_20-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_20-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_21-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_22-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_22-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way i can display only first unique generated class? In my example i have 2 events for 20-06, one for 21-6 and two for 22-6. Having a hard time achieving something similar to

```
.event_date_[all-dates] {display:none;}
.event_date_[first-iteration-of-a-date]:first-of-type {display:block;}
```

So far i was able with jQuery to get only the generated classes, but need to add css only to the first unique class.

```
jQuery('div[class^="event_date_"]').each(function(i){
                jQuery(this).css("color", "blue");

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probhably not the easiest way, but you can just do some grouping on all the elements to find the first of each group and apply css styles to that group

```js
var $elems = jQuery('div[class^="event_date_"]')

var firstofGroup = Object.values($elems.get().reduce( (acc,e) => {
    const cls = e.classList[0];
    acc[cls] ||= [], acc[cls].push(e);
    return acc
},{})).map(x => x[0])

$(firstofGroup).css("color","blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_20-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_20-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_21-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_22-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_22-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right you can't do this just with CSS.

You can identify all the unique classes by finding them and adding them to a `Set`, then loop through the set using each class and jQuery's `:first` pseudo-class to do something on the first occurrence of each (in this example, turning them blue, but you can do whatever you need to do to them):

```
const classes = new Set($('[class^="event_date_"]').map((_, e) => {
    return e.className.match(/event_date_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/)[0];
}).get());
for (const cls of classes) {
    $(`.${cls}:first`).css("color", "blue");
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const classes = new Set($('[class^="event_date_"]').map((_, e) => {
    return e.className.match(/event_date_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/)[0];
}).get());

for (const cls of classes) {
    $(`.${cls}:first`).css("color", "blue");
}
```

```html
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_20-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_20-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_21-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_22-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_22-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you could build one big selector by combining those with commas in-between, but it seems harder to read and maintain:

```
$([...classes].map(
    (cls) => `.${cls}:first`
).join(","))
.css("color", "blue");
```

Live Example:

```js
const classes = new Set($('[class^="event_date_"]').map((_, e) => {
    return e.className.match(/event_date_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/)[0];
}).get());

$([...classes].map(
    (cls) => `.${cls}:first`
).join(","))
.css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_20-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_20-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_21-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_22-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
 <div class="event_date_22-06-2020">title event</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could move the date class up one level, to the event container, you can solve this with the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).

So your code would be (I've numbered the events so the effect is more apparent):

```css
.event_date_20-06-2020 + .event_date_20-06-2020,
.event_date_22-06-2020 + .event_date_22-06-2020 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="event event_date_20-06-2020">
 <div>title event 1</div>
</div>
<div class="event event_date_20-06-2020">
 <div>title event 2</div>
</div>
<div class="event event_date_21-06-2020">
 <div>title event 3</div>
</div>
<div class="event event_date_22-06-2020">
 <div>title event 4</div>
</div>
<div class="event event_date_22-06-2020">
 <div>title event 5</div>
</div>
```